# Decimal URI Parameter don't working MVC API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My API is giving me error if I use 1.xx parameter, but with 0.9 the API is working.

```
var hPParameter = hP.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("HP", hP) :
                new ObjectParameter("HP", typeof(decimal));
```

My method

```
        public IEnumerable<FP_getResult3_Result> Get(int CDT, decimal HP, int flow, int fam, int app)
    {  
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return db.FP_getResult3(CDT, HP, flow, fam, app).ToList();
    }
```

My urls:

```
Works:        http://localhost:64134/api/Result?CDT=134&HP=0.9&flow=4&fam=1&app=1
Doesn't work: http://localhost:64134/api/Result?CDT=134&HP=1.9&flow=4&fam=1&app=1
```

I don't know what to do. Hope someone can help me.

It give me this error: Error converting data type numeric to decimal.

When I run the statement on Database it work good.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Request is invalid

Comment: what is you method signature , can you please show that

Comment: @PranayRana why did you undo my edit?  We could actually compare the URLs.  Now we can't.

Comment: @Amy - not undo i just updated text in code form...just added `code` for link..is there any issue ..you can change it back

Comment: @PranayRana if you look at the edit history, you absolutely threw my edit away.

Comment: @Amy - reverted back...apologies

Comment: I just added my method.

Comment: if the only difference between the URLs is 0.9 vs. 1.9 then I'd first step through `FP_getResult3` in the debugger. or does it not even get that far in the second case?

Comment: Is this MVC or Web API?  There is no "MVC API"

Comment: I'm sorry, it's an Web API

Comment: It gives me this error.

'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

Comment: That's just the name of the error. You need to provide more detail: the message, inner exceptions etc. Remember, we're not at your computer so we only know what you tell us.

Comment: I fixed my problem, the stored procedure had as paraemeter decimal(25,25), it didn't allowed numbers before the point. Thank you all.